# Printing in a Windows Service

Tags: windows, vb.net, printing, service

I'm trying to print in a Windows Service. The following VB.Net code is used:

```
    Dim _pd As New System.Drawing.Printing.PrintDocument()

    AddHandler _pd.PrintPage, New System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventHandler(AddressOf PrintDocument_PrintPage)
    AddHandler _pd.EndPrint, New System.Drawing.Printing.PrintEventHandler(AddressOf PrintDocument_EndPrint)

    _pd.Print()
```

The EventHandlers are implemented and tested. When I run the code (with AccountType: User) I'm getting an exception saying, that "no printer is installed". In a Windows Forms Application everything works.

I'm using a Network printer.

Thank you in advance,
Alexander

Comment: Does the account that the service is running as have any printers setup?

Comment: The Windows Forms Application, in which the code working, runns on the same account as the service (I only got one user installed on my machine).

Comment: are the printers installed locally, or are they network printers

Comment: I'm using a network printer, but it is installed through the "Install printers wizard" locally and works fine in my Windows Forms applications.

Comment: @alxppp if I may ask, did you se a timer? what timer did you use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Printing in Windows Services is not recommended.

you need to use a [different account](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.serviceaccount.aspx) for your service,( domain account) so that you can access network resources.

You can find more info at: [Network printing with window service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3996047/network-printing-with-window-service/3996570#3996570)

Answer (score 1):

Try this code, it can make you print anything:

```
Dim psi As New ProcessStartInfo
psi.UseShellExecute = True
psi.Verb = "print"
psi.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden
psi.FileName = sReport
Process.Start(psi)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can print via Windows service with the help of windows APIs. System.Drawing.Printing doesn't go well with service.

Check this link : http://support.microsoft.com/kb/322090