# Windows service credentials

Tags: c#, service, credentials, printing-web-page

I have a Windows service that should print out HTML text.
The OS is 7, with .NET 4.5.1 and IE 11.

The code:

```
    private static void PrintOnStaThread(string text)
    {
        using (WebBrowser webBrowser = new WebBrowser())
        {
            webBrowser.Navigate("about:blank");
            webBrowser.Document.OpenNew(false);

            while (webBrowser.DocumentText != text && webBrowser.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)
            {
                webBrowser.Document.Write(text);
                webBrowser.Refresh();
                Application.DoEvents();
            }

            InternetExplorer internetExplorer = (InternetExplorer)webBrowser.ActiveXInstance;
            internetExplorer.ExecWB(OLECMDID.OLECMDID_PRINT, OLECMDEXECOPT.OLECMDEXECOPT_DONTPROMPTUSER, Win32.PRINT_WAITFORCOMPLETION);
        }
    }
```

The problem:
When the service is logged using the `Local System` account the `ExecWB` function does nothing and the thread is exiting without any exception. When the service is logged using the Administrator credentials the `ExecWB` function works perfectly, but I don't want to use this account.

Any comments will be welcome.

Comment: Don't use WinForms within a Windows Service. The problem is most likely caused by that. Use a different way to print HTML. If you must, see [Print html document from Windows Service in C# without print dialog](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/416314/print-html-document-from-windows-service-in-c-sharp-without-print-dialog), but that still uses the `WebBrowser` control. See also [Print html document from Windows Service without print dialog](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/419412/print-html-document-from-windows-service-without-print-dialog).

Comment: I've know and used the first example in my code. I don't really understand what do you mean by "Don't usee WinForms". I don't think I am.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, but you need to configure your service to be "Interactive".

For further information, have a look to this document http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683502(v=vs.85).aspx